# Input file element's docx file's content type is not correct?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I know that the docx's MIME type is

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

But whenever I pick an docx file using `<input type="file">`, the type is empty ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple><br><br>
  <button onclick="logFile(event)">CLick</button>

</body>

<script>
function logFile(e) {
    var myFile = document.getElementById("myfile");
    console.table(myFile.files[0])
}
</script>
</html>
```

This code will log a table with `type = application/pdf` when you pick an pdf, but when you pick a docx file `type = ""`

Because of the type is empty, when I send it to my server, the browser auto read the docx files as `application/octet-stream`, which is **not what I want**

Answer (score 0):

MIME types are not really a browser/client thing. Especially Windows knows nothing about them and uses the file extension instead, and neither it nor browsers have have a list or mapping of file extensions to MIME types.

Additionally, even if the browser would send a MIME type, you **NEVER** can trust anything that a client sends to you. You will in any case need to look at the content of sent file and check if it actually is the file type you expect.

Comment: But I have no control over the backend. The backend check the type sent from the frontend to do some logic. And If I am using postman for example, I can see the the type are actually correct. But when I sent from the browser, the type is just simply wrong